# virtuemart 1.x number products in hp

Tags: virtuemart

I searched that common issue but I didn't find almost anything...
I'd like to display just the amount of products I got (just 2 categories, but I need only one) in HP. Where can I found that variable and where do I have to "print" to see it on homepage? joomla 1.5.22, VM 1.1.5
Thanks a lot

Comment: Isn't there a readily available (not to mention, free) module for this? Joomla 1.5 and Virtuemart 1.1.x are not "get number and print" systems - to do it "their way" you have to employ a module (either from a 3rd partz, or self created one) to be able to display something (other than main content) on the site.

Comment: I was thinking is not necessary to have a module. Just "catching" the amount of products code and print it on homepage with a personalized html. I was thinking... ^_^